# is writing in /tmp/ detectable for a too-much-memory software killer?

Tags: linux, temp

I've got a general question and I don't really find a correct explanation.

I have a program which is creating big files in */tmp/*;

Theses files are created as follow :

```
 FILE *tmp;
 tmp = fopen(argv[i-1]+3, "w");
```

And I've got another program, checking all the executable and killing all the process which are using too much memory.

*My question is as follow:*

Is the first program in danger ? 
or writing in */tmp/* is considered a **disk space used** and not **memory used** ?

Thanks in advance for your answer,

Best Regards.

Comment: StackOverflow is explicitly for questions about writing software. This might be a better question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Do you want to know if files in `/tmp` are stored on RAM? Or do you want to know if the size of used files in `/tmp` is added to statistics about memory usage (assuming `/tmp` is in RAM)?

Comment: ...and for the latter, it depends very specifically *which* statistics are in use, and *how*, specifically, those files are being accessed -- if the measure is virtual memory and they're `mmap`'d it's a different answer from content generated with normal writes.

Comment: I want to know if the size used by files in /tmp will be detected by the 2nd software and considered as memory use.

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail, ...see my comment -- whether they'll be detected as memory usage depends on details you haven't provided. In general, however, the answer is "no".

Comment: There are not `mmap`, basically I'm just redirecting some output into a file in /tmp/ (to have right to write) but I could have redirect anywhere. It's a really simple `fopen()`, `fprintf`, `fclose`.

Comment: Won't be detected, then.

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail I thing when you are accessing the files using `fopen`, it will not count for the second application. But I do no really know it. It is just my intension since you can not access the data just like accessing the memory (it is not mapped in memory).

Comment: I think your topic/header provides some misconception. Maybe this is the reason why the question is "on hold" now.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which type of file system (or "implementation of how the files are stored") /tmp uses. It may be on disk, or in memory.

Check in the file /etc/fstab. If you have a line like this, with `tmpfs`, /tmp will be in main memory:

```
none /tmp tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

Comment: Actually -- the OP is asking not just if writing to /tmp uses RAM, but if writing to /tmp risks being killed by software monitoring memory usage. That's a different question, with a different answer: Even if `/tmp` *is* a tmpfs mount, most tools attempting to kill software allocating excessive memory won't recognize its usage as such (unless they're measuring virtual memory usage and the files in `/tmp` are mmap'd).